# Replace a part of a word using c#

Tags: c#

I need to change the string "DT1OutPassFail" as "DT4OutPassFail". I need to find "DT1" in the input string and replace it with "DT4" to get the output string. I need to do this using c#. "DT1" is the value in textbox1 and "DT4" is the value in textbox2. I tried the following options. But it dosent work.

```
string input = "DT1OutPassFail";
string newstring;

newstring = input.Replace(textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text);

newstring = Regex.Replace(input,textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string replaceString(string value)
{
    string newValue;
    string findValue;
    string replaceValue;

    findValue = textBox1.Text;
    replaceValue = textBox2.Text;

    if(value.StartsWith(findValue))
        newValue = value.Replace(findValue, replaceValue);
    else
        newValue = value;

    return newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way instead:

```
//The Original string
string input = "DT1OutPassFail";
//The string which you want to replace with DT1
string input2="DT4";
//Just check whether the string contains DT1 then replace it with input2
var result = input.Contains("DT1") ? input.Replace("DT1", input2) : input;
```